# How to find contents of an XML Node that starts with an apostrophe?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I have some code that I am using to try to learn XML parsing in VB.NET. (Not even really sure if this is the way to go; just wanted to see if my understanding of what I was currently reading was accurate, so bear with me on the beginner level programming).

```
    XMLQuotes = New XmlDocument
    XMLQuotes.Load("XMLDocs/IKAbx.xml")

    Dim nodAuthor As XmlElement = XMLQuotes.DocumentElement
    Dim nodItems As XmlNodeList = nodAuthor.SelectNodes("/Authors/Author")
    For i = 0 To nodItems.Count - 1
        'grab info from the XML using the supplied node
        authorName = GetNodeValue("Name", doc)
        'etc.

        'try to get a list of quotes from the author.

'the next line is the line that does not work.
        Dim nodQuotes As XmlNodeList = nodReqs.SelectNodes("/Authors/Author[Name='" & Replace(nodItems(i).Item("Name").InnerXml, "'", "&#39;") & "']/Quote")
        For j = 0 To nodQuotes.Count - 1
            quotes.Add nodBonSk(j).InnerXml
        Next

        'continue processing
    Next I
```

This process works great, with one exception.  If I have a quote that starts with an apostrophe (such as "'Tis nobler in the hearts..." [and yes, I do know that that quote starts with "Whether", but this is to illustrate the point at hand]), then it does not actually find the node with the appropriate Name element.  It returns a count of 0 nodes and moves on.

I have tried using the &apos, &#39 escape characters in the XML file (an d even tried just a pure single quote), but nothing seems to work.
So, what am I doing wrong?

```
Private Function GetNodeValue(nodeName As String, doc As String) As Object
    Dim doc2 As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(doc)
    Dim element = doc2.Root.Element(nodeName)

    If IsNothing(element) Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Return element.Value
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send SelectNodes a string that uses double-quotes as string delimiters.  For VB.Net, use double double-quotes to escape a double-quote within a string, since strings are themselves delimited by double-quotes.

```
Dim cXQuery as String
cXQuery = "/Authors/Author[Name=""" & nodItems(i).Item("Name").InnerXml & """]/Quote

Dim nodQuotes As XmlNodeList 
nodQuotes = nodReqs.SelectNodes(cXQuery)
```

(You also probably want to grab an `XMLNode` object for each `Authors/Author` element, and then just call `selectNodes("Quote")` to get each author's quotes, although that's not what you asked about.)

Comment: Thank you.  That is exactly what I needed.  And I will look into creating the XMLNode.  As I said, I am just starting out on this (a little late to the game I am).